# Why does browser zoom in affect slickgrid autotooltip functioning, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, slickgrid

The issue is that tooltips are still appearing even when values aren't truncated.

The behavior varies in different browsers. In chrome, starting at 110%, the autotooltip isn't working correctly already. In firefox and IE, you have to zoom in more to replicate this issue.

My hunch is that cell widths are being messed up when zooming in the page but I'm not so familiar how each browsers scale the elements in the page. I'm also uncertain if there are ways to control this?

Any ideas on why this is happening and possible ways to fix this?